# How to use LIMIT in sub-query with JPA Criteria?

Tags: jpa, subquery, limit, criteria

I want to make a query within it has a su-query, then this will make the query.

```
SELECT * FROM orders orda WHERE orda.id_orders IN
(SELECT ordb.id_orders FROM orders ordb WHERE orda.identifier = ordb.identifier LIMIT 1)
```

Currently my structure is as follows with other parameters:

```
return new Specification<Orders>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Orders> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                Subquery<Orders> ordersSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Orders.class);
                Root rootB = ordersSubquery.from(Orders.class);
                ordersSubquery.select(rootB.get(Orders_.id_orders));
                ordersSubquery.where(cb.equal(root.get(Orders_.identifier), rootB.get(Orders_.identifier)));
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(Orders_.created_at)));
                criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(Orders_.created_at));
                Predicate temp = cb.and(
                        root.get(Orders_.id_orders).in(ordersSubquery)
                );
                return temp;
            }
        };
```

Can anyone help as I include the LIMIT statement in the sub-query? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `criteriaBuilder.min(rootB.<Number>get(Orders_.id_orders))` in your select statement. This should work.